# Multiline text box

Tags: regex

I  have a text box and a regular expression for the string(path of a file) i.e:

```
 "(((https)[:]{1}[//]{2}[a-z0-9]*.xyz[/]{1}([A-Za-z]*[/]{1}[A-Za-z]*.json(/n)?))?)+";
```

to be entered in the text box. Now I want to enter multiple strings in the text box separated by /n.

How can it be done?

Comment: *"multiple strings separated by /n."* -- you probably want multiple strings separated by the [newline character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline). Some languages (including `regex`) use `\n` to encode a newline character. Depending on the programming language you use to handle the string, you might not need to encode the newline in the regex but either split the string to lines and handle each line individually or tell the `regex` that the input string is multi-line. Provide more information about the way you use the `regex`.

Comment: Add several examples of the strings, you're trying to match. You can also use [online services](https://regex101.com/) to develop your regular expressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `[\r\n]+` to you're regex , that will match multiple consecutive new-lines.

You can add examples of the string you're trying to match .

Hope that'll help you